# Passing local user-defined function (custom filter) as parameter to the class method?

Tags: php, class, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I'm wondering is it possible somehow?

### sample code

```
class CustomFilter {
  ...
  function FilterData($data, $function_name) {
    # here I want to execute that function against $data argument
    }
  ...
  }

function add2($x) {
  return $x + 2;
  }

$fd = new CustomFilter;
$fd->FilterData(5, ‘add2’);
```

I can pass function name and execute it using [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) outside of class, but inside the class that function is not visible. Is it any way to make user-defined function work inside the class?

What's the idea?

Using class constructor user passes configuration array into class. Part of array may contain different filter parameters, example:

### config array

```
$cfg = array(
  'image' => array(
    'params' => array(
      '+src' => 'string[filter:url]',
      'maxwidth' => 'integer[filter:1+]',
      'byte' => 'integer[filter:0-255]',
      'alt' => 'string',
      'align' => 'string[values:left|right|center]',
      'binary' => false
      ),
    ...
    ),
  ...
  );
```

Filter parameters define filter criteria for some input fields. In this example '`string[filter:url]`' calls some inner method to check if parameter 'src' is valid url parameter, '`integer[filter:1+]`' checks if value is integer greater than 1, '`false`' means "don't filter value". But one possible value is '`string[customfilter:myfunction]`' and that means "check argument with user-defined function myfunction".

**I need to set local function name as string and execute it inside the class.**

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
$function_name($data);
```

Inside your `dataFilter` function.

**Example:**

```
class CustomFilter {
  function FilterData($data, $function_name) {
     $function_name($data);
  }
}

function add2($x) {
  echo $x + 2;
}

$fd = new CustomFilter;
$fd->FilterData(5, 'add2');
```

**Result:**

```
7
```

Comment: That easy? Never thought that way, even didn't know it's possible. Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the function with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) or [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func):

```
function FilterData($data, $function_name) {
  call_user_func($function_name, $data);
}
```